# Where do we need to change parameters in websphere application server?

Tags: websphere, session-variables, jvm-arguments

In my environment I have a DMGR server on different physical server and Node on different one. I need to change session related parameters (replication interval). I have the script created at both levels (DMGR and node). So where I need to change?

I have done the changes at node level only but its not replicated and I lost my back-up file.

Answer (score 0):

In WebSphere ND you need to change any settings on DMGR only, DMGR distribute all settings to Nodes via NodeAgents.

Comment: i thought the same that DMGR changes are need to replicate at Node level  but i have seen  different time stamp at DMGR level and Node level.